# How to make custom authentication in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I tried to make a custom login authentication using Oracle APEX. But when i tried to login it say "Invalid Login Credentials"
My_User SQL database is

```
CREATE TABLE  "MY_USERS" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "USERNAME" VARCHAR2(60), 
    "PASSWORD" VARCHAR2(20), 
    "DEPARTMENT" VARCHAR2(20), 
    "STATUS" VARCHAR2(20), 
    "USER_ROLL" VARCHAR2(20), 
     PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE, 
     UNIQUE ("USERNAME")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE, 
     UNIQUE ("PASSWORD")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   )
/
```

and for the custom authentication, the PL/SQL code is

```
FUNCTION user_aut    (
 P_USERNAME IN VARCHAR2, --User_Name
 P_PASSWORD IN VARCHAR2 -- Password    
)
 RETURN BOOLEAN
AS
 lc_pwd_exit VARCHAR2 (1);
BEGIN
 -- Validate whether the user exits or not
 SELECT 'Active'
 INTO lc_pwd_exit
 FROM MY_USERS
 WHERE upper(username) = UPPER (P_USERNAME) AND password = P_PASSWORD and status='Active' 
;
RETURN TRUE;
EXCEPTION
 WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
 THEN
 RETURN FALSE;
END user_aut;
```

Here is my login details
[login details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RY9CH.png)
Anyone can help me how to fix this? I'm new in Oracle Apex Thank you

Comment: Looks like you entered invalid combination of username/password.

Comment: i have enter a valid username and password but still show invalid login credentials. Any suggestion? @Littlefoot

Comment: Edit the original message you posted and show us contents of the MY_USERS table for username you used while trying to log in to Apex application, as well as values you actually entered into the login page items. By the way, why is PASSWORD column constrained with UNIQUE constraint? Why would two (or more) users have the same password (without knowing it, of course)?

Comment: Ok i have show the my_users data for the username and password @Littlefoot

Comment: According to that, if you entered `testingapex@gamil.com` as username (using any letter case, as function converts it to uppercase) and literally `Apex!123` as its password (paying attention to letter case, as password is used *as is* in the function), function should return TRUE and let you in as its status is `Active`.

Comment: are you able to execute that function in sql workshop successfully ?

Comment: Yes, i already find the issue @Koen Lostrie